# ¿cómo calcular el campo de una columna de una tabla mediante 2 columnas de la misma?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, datatables, stored-procedure, sql-server-2017

tengo 2 columnas `TonEntrega,Usdentregada,GrupoPrecio,TestPrecio` del tipo float, en mi tabla `tmpcuboventa` en SQLSERVER 2017,quiero calcular el total de la venta restando de la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE tmpcuboventa 
SET Contribucion = ((TonEntregada/USDEntregada)-(GrupoTesPrecio - TonUniPedido))
```

tengo errores al momento de dividir con los momentos ya que algunos campos tienen 0, con los quisiera que por favor me ayuden a como podría sumarlos y solucionar el tema de los 0.

Comment: Saludos, Te sugiero crear función en SQL Server donde pases esos valores y realices la(s) operación(ones) necesarias. Así validas antes de caer en el escenario/error de División por Cero `Numero/Cero`; desde luego dependiendo los valores que tu campo `Contribucion` admita puede ser que su valor sea `NULL` o `0` según definas.

Comment: ¿Cuál resultado quieres obtener si USDEntregada es cero?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si algo vale 0, vas tener que decidir que hacer.. o poner 0 directamente para esos casos.. en ese caso, con hacer dos querys alcanzaria... podes aclarar bien que necesitas?

Comment: En la columna USDEntregada tiene en  algunos casos  valor 0,son poco pero hay,la columna tiene el valor float

Comment: Eso quedó claro, pero no responde la pregunta que se te ha hecho.

Comment: Se me ocurre de la nada, ¿Y si haces un where y limitas a que USDEntregada sea mayor a cero?

Comment: el resultado que quiero obtener es la diferencia de todos esos campos que es el valor que irá en la columna contribucion : la division de (TonEntregada/UsdEntregada) - (GrupoTestPrecio-TonUnipedido) ,la diferencia entre ellos es la contribucion.

Comment: @LuarC a lo que se refiere Luis Cazares es que en caso que USDEntregada valga 0, cual debería ser el comportamiento del calculo, ¿convertir la división en 0 o simplemente obviar ese cálculo?, si no respondes eso es dificil ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: A bueno lo entendí mal,disculpen ,en caso sea 0 deberá reemplazarse con  el valor de 1.

Answer (score 0):

Una división por cero siempre provocará un error, por lo que debes eliminar esa posibilidad. La mejor opción es actualizar solo aquellos registros cuyo valor del denominador (`USDEntregada`) no sea cero.

```
UPDATE tmpcuboventa 
SET Contribucion = ((TonEntregada/USDEntregada)-(GrupoTesPrecio - TonUniPedido))
WHERE USDEntregada <> 0
```

Luego deberás saber si es necesario realizar alguna acción adicionar en aquellos registros cuya columna `USDEntregada` sea 0 o tenga valor nulo.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda,lo voy a probar y les digo como me fue y los cambios que hice de ser necesarios.

Answer (score 0):

Según los comentarios, creo que podrias intentar hacer un `CASE` en el que especifiques que si `USDEntregada` es `0` o `NULL`, se haga un cálculo diferente, algo así:

```
UPDATE tmpcuboventa 
SET Contribucion = CASE 
    WHEN USDEntregada = 0 OR USDEntregada IS NULL THEN TonEntregada-(GrupoTesPrecio - TonUniPedido) 
    ELSE ((TonEntregada/USDEntregada)-(GrupoTesPrecio - TonUniPedido)) 
END
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda,lo voy a probar y les digo como me fue y los cambios que hice de ser necesarios.

Comment: @LuarC Toma en cuenta que en mi ejemplo, cuando `USDEntregada` es `0` o `NULL`, por tu comentario de que debía ser 1, asumi que te referias a dividir `TonEntregada` entre 1, por lo que sería como poner solamente `TonEntregada`, si te refieres a que toda la división debe valer 1, entonces debes cambiarlo en el `CASE`. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Josue por la aclaracion,lo tendré presente,

Answer (score 0):

Puedes evitar el error de división por cero convirtiendo explicitamente ese valor en `NULL`, lo que hará que la operación aritmética devuelva `NULL` lo cuál, además, es semanticamente correcto, pues el valor de la división por cero es *indeterminado* y justamente ese es uno de los significados de `NULL`: valor desconocido o *indeterminado*.

Para lograrlo, utiliza la función [`nullif`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
UPDATE tmpcuboventa 
   SET Contribucion = ((TonEntregada / Nullif(USDEntregada, 0)) -(GrupoTesPrecio - TonUniPedido));
```

Luego de ejecutar esta consulta, todas las filas que tengan valor 0 en `USDEntregada` tendrán valor `NULL` en la columna `Contribucion`.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda,lo voy a probar y les aviso